# Casting a Scala Object into a Generic type?

Tags: scala, generics, scalatest

Firstly, some background:

I'm currently writing a generic solver for a certain class of problems (specifically, a structural SVM solver) in Scala. In order to use this, the user has to implement an interface.

Consider a simplified version of the interface:

```
trait HelperFunctions[X, Y] {
    def func1(x: X, y: Y): Y
    def func2(y1: Y, y2: Y): Int
}
```

and a simple implementation:

```
object ImplFunctions extends HelperFunctions[Vector[Double], Double] {
    def func1(x: Vector[Double], y: Double): Double  = { ... }
    def func2(y1: Double, y2: Double): Int = { .. }
}
```

(Note that the implementation **has** to be provided in form of an object.)

Now, the problem:
I need to write a diagnostic suite which aids the user to verify the sanity of his functions. An example sanity test would involve something like `func1(..)` being positive for all `x` and `y`. For this, I set out by writing a BDD-style unit-tests using ScalaTest.

Note that the diagnostic suite should be generic, to work with any object which extends `HelperFunctions[X, Y]`. 
A high-level picture of how I planned to go about this: first providing all the sanity tests designed for generic `X` and `Y`. Then, the user merely replaces, say a `???`, with a `ImplFunctions` and runs the suite.

But, turns out I didn't find an elegant approach to treat `ImplFunctions` as a generic `HelperFunctions[X, Y]`. Here's a taste of what I've tried so far:

```
import org.scalatest._

class ApplicationDiag extends FlatSpec {

  // Option 1:
  // Cast the ImplFunctions into a generic type
  // ERROR: type mismatch; found : ImplFunctions.type, required : HelperFunctions[X, Y]
  val helpers: HelperFunctions[X, Y] = ImplFunctions
  // OR
  def helpers[X, Y](): HelperFunctions[X, Y] = ImplFunctions


  // Option 2: User fills up the right side, no type specified for the value
  // WORKS. But, cannot explicitly state types
  val helpers = ImplFunctions

  "func1" should "be positive" in {
    // ... the check as described previously
   }

}
```

Due to the covariance nature, I imagine it should be possible to cast an instance of a type to its supertype. But, it seems to be tougher since this involves generics.
Is there a clean way to do this?

Note:
1. I'm totally open to alternate designs for the diagnostic suite.
2. The real-world interface: [HelperFunctions](https://github.com/dalab/dissolve-struct/blob/master/dissolve-struct-lib/src/main/scala/ch/ethz/dalab/dissolve/optimization/DissolveFunctions.scala) and a real-world application: [ImplFunctions](https://github.com/dalab/dissolve-struct/blob/master/dissolve-struct-examples/src/main/scala/ch/ethz/dalab/dissolve/examples/chain/ChainDemo.scala)

Comment: If you want your types to be co or contra-variant you should declare them as such using the `+X`/`-X` syntax. You shouldn't need to cast.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you write your generic tests, but maybe you should consider using [type classes](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/02/06/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-12-type-classes.html).

I'm going to use slightly simpler interfaces to demonstrate the idea but it should be easily applicable to your problem.
For example, you have an interface

```
trait Helpers[A] {
  def f(a: A): A
}
```

And an implementation

```
object IntImpl extends Helpers[Int] {
  def f(a: Int) = -a
}
```

Unfortunately, `Helpers[A]` does not require any constraints on `A` which would be nice. But you probably do not want do modify the library.

It is still possible to write a generic test suite for some `A`s:

```
class Diag[A : Numeric](h: Helpers[A]) {
  val fromInt = implicitly[Numeric[A]].fromInt _

  // just some assertions, using scalatests here should also work
  assert(h.f(fromInt(0)) == fromInt(0))
  assert(h.f(fromInt(1)) == fromInt(1)) // will fail with IntImpl
}
```

This suite can be used with every `A` for which we have an implementation of the `Numeric` type class (e.g. `Int`).

The concrete suite can now be instantiated with:

```
new Diag(IntImpl)
```

or if the test framework requires a class

```
class ImplDiag extends Diag(IntImpl)
```

This approach has the advantage that it is completely type-safe. You do not have to cast anything and the signature of `Diag` clearly specifies what is required to run the suite.